# Were there others guarding/guiding to the Soul Stone?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Infinity War*, we see The Red Skull at Vormir guiding those who came to collect the Soul Stone.

But since these infinity stones existed long before the events of Captain America, do we know if there were others guiding to the Soul Stone before Red Skull?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Not really.

In MCU, there is no explanation if someone was guiding Soul Stone before Red Skull so we can assume there was no one. Besides this, this stone doesn't require someone guarding it. One has to make a sacrifice to obtain this, i.e. a soul for a soul. Red Skull couldn't do this so he just guides others to how to achieve Soul Stone.

It seems he was cursed with the knowledge about Soul Stone and to know the name of everyone who arrives there.

> It is my curse to know all who journey here.

and later...

> A lifetime ago, I, too, sought the stones. I even held one in my hand. But it cast me out, banished me here. Guiding others to a treasure I cannot possess.

Comment: Thanks. If that's the case, this leads me to wonder who guided the Red Skull about the soul for a soul concept.

Comment: I have no proof, but it seems when he was banished, he was cursed by soul stone to possess the knowledge about it and know the name of everyone who arrives there.